# How to programmatically select an item (or many) in MultiSelectionComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, syncfusion

Let's say I have a `multiSelectionComboBox` from Synfusion with items in Windows Forms like this :

```
multiSelectionComboBoxDays.Items.Add("Monday");
multiSelectionComboBoxDays.Items.Add("Tuesday");
multiSelectionComboBoxDays.Items.Add("Wednesday");
...
```

I want "Tuesday" and "Wednesday" items to be selected by default. 
I tried :

```
multiSelectionComboBoxDays.SelectedItems = "Tuesday";
multiSelectionComboBoxDays.SelectedItem = "Tuesday";
```

and other variants with no success.

I know I can use `SelectAll()` and `UnSelectAll()`, but this is not what I want.

How can I programmatically select an item (or many) in MultiSelectionComboBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
multiSelectionComboBoxDays.SelectedItems.Add()
multiSelectionComboBoxDays.AddVisualItem()
```

It's been a while since I used Syncfusion, so I might be a tad rusty

Comment: Thank you, it works, but not as expected ...
Now : https://www.screencast.com/t/jdDyfh07CfS
Expected : https://www.screencast.com/t/K5pGBWfOG8
(I don't know what is the best/recommended way to share images here)

Comment: Does adding the same item to the SelectedValues collection fix the issue? Failing that, trying to raise a CollectionChanged event on the SelectedItems?

Sorry, doing most of this from memory

Comment: Sorry, `SelectedValues` doesn't exist, only `SelectedValue` and I don't really know how to raise a `SelectedItemCollectionChanged` (Syncfusion's documentation is really weak). I tried `Refresh()` with no success

Comment: I edited my answer to include what I think the correct call is